# Datastax Driver Mapping API

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Does anyone know if Datastax has or is planning on releasing mapping/annotation support for batch statements?  I am loving the new mapping & annotation abstraction, but haven't seen anything for batch statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this for both Annotations and Mapping Objects by getting Statements from them and adding them to a batch.

With the @Accessor annotation you can get the statement form the Accessor and then add it to a batch

Here's an example from the [unit tests](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-mapping/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/MapperTest.java#L281).  PostAccessor.updateCountQuery is a defined Statement in an @Accessor annotated interface:

```java
@Accessor
public interface PostAccessor {
    @Query("UPDATE ks.posts SET content=? WHERE user_id=? AND post_id=?")
    public Statement updateContentQuery(String newContent, UUID userId, UUID postId);
}
```

The statement can then be generated and used in the [following way](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-mapping/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/MapperTest.java#L352):

```java
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.add(postAccessor.updateContentQuery("Something different", p1.getUserId(), p1.getPostId()));
batch.add(postAccessor.updateContentQuery("A different something", p2.getUserId(), p2.getPostId()));
manager.getSession().execute(batch);
```

For Pojos with Crud operations you can simply call ['mapper.saveQuery(entity)'](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/mapping/Mapper.html#saveQuery(T)) to get a Statement back and then add it to a batch.

[Post](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!searchin/java-driver-user/batch/java-driver-user/e2HJHSUJa1I/8AaQXtJ_HncJ) from the user list where I got this info from.